# Words with friends cannot be accessed since update

Tags: ipad

Words with friends has been updated and now I can't get in because I don't have a safari password. How do I get one? I have been playing this for a long time until the update. there is an ad between each play and now I can't cancel it by pressing the x.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you are asking? "Words" is pretty broad.

Comment: What 'Safari password' are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

"Words With Friends" is a Scrabble-like game available for many platforms.

As someone that has played in the past (but quickly gave up after days would pass between turns), I recall you had an option to either sign in with the app itself or use a Facebook login... I believe mostly for contact/friend matching, sending invites, polluting your Wall with game updates, etc.

If you're unaware of your password, perhaps you had it linked to a Facebook account before an app update was applied, logging you out?

There are both free-to-play and paid versions, but the former is supported with ads, as you've noted.